# Algorithm - managing order of an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a solution for this problem.

I have an array which defines the rule of the order of elements like below.

```
let rule = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K]
```

I then have another array whose element can be removed or added back.
So for example, I have a list like this:

```
var list = [A,D,E,I,J,K]
```

Now If I want to add element 'B' to 'list' the list should be

```
var list = [A,B,D,E,I,J,K]
```

because 'B' comes after 'A' and before 'D' in the rule array. So the insertion index would be 1 in this case.

The item in the array are not comparable each other (Let's say a developer can change the order of rule list at any time if that make sense). And there needs no duplicates in the array.

I'm not sure if I explained the problem clearly, but I'd like to know a good approach that finds an insertion index.

Comment: you can assign value to the letters? and then use binary search to find the insertion point?

Comment: Can there be duplicates, or are the items unique? I take it the items aren't actually comparable to each other? e.g. you don't know B comes after A without having to refer to the rule array

Comment: No duplicates and elements are not comparable.

Comment: What do you mean by "the elements in the array are not comparable"? Doesn't the question define a comparison between them -- namely "after or before in the list." But are they hashable?

Comment: Elements "must" be comparable. Otherwise " 'B' comes after 'A' and before 'D' " wouldn't make sense. Basically, the comparison here is "who comes earlier in the rule list"?

Comment: No, I mean the order in the rule list doesn't conform to actual order of the value type,, so if the type of the rule array is integer, then a developer can define the rule like [4,3,6,1,2] etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained the Python code in comments. Basically, find the right place to insert the new element using binary search. The order of elements is decided using `rank`. The below code assumes that if `elements` is non-empty then the `rule` is followed by items in the `elements`.

```
rule = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']
rank = dict()
for i in range(len(rule)):
    rank[rule[i]] = i

elements = ['A','D','E','I','J','K'] #list in which we wish to add elements
target = 'B'    #element to be inserted

#Binary search to find the right place to insert the target in elements
left, right = 0, len(elements)
while left < right:
    mid = left + (right - left) // 2
    if rank[elements[mid]] >= rank[target]:
        right = mid
    else:
        left = mid + 1

elements.insert(left, target) #left is the insertion index
print(elements)
```

Time complexity of add: O(log(len(elements))) 
Space complexity: O(1)

Comment: Define a dict for `rule` areay and after that when want to insert new item to `list` check keys of dictionaries and check item key with `rule` dict to define order. After that find pre and post item in list and insert it to that.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago: You got it!! Fun problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If the items are unique (only can occur once), and are not comparable to each other (don't know that B comes after A), then.

1. Iterate through the rules and find the items position in the rule array.
2. Check if it is the first item in rules, if so insert at the first position and skip the other steps.
3. Check to see if it is the last item in rules, if so insert at the end and skip the other steps.
4. Select the value of the item 1 before into a variable A.
5. Select the value of the item 1 after into a variable B.
6. Iterate through the list,
   if you encounter the value in parameter A insert it after that value, if you encounter the value B, add the value before that.
7. If you come to the end without finding either value A or B, then you need to repeat but with values 2 before and 2 after the item in the rules (again checking to see if you hit the start or end of the rules list).

You will probably want to make 6 & 7 a function that calls itself recursively.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is, we can use one iteration of [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

So, we start from right side of array compare our input `x` with array elements a go from right to left side. if we arrive an index `i` of array that `let[i]<=x` then `let[i+1]` is correct location that `x` can be insert.
This approach that has time complexity `O(n)`, follow from correctness of Insertion sort.

**Note that the lower of your problem is `O(n)` because your data structure is array so you need after each insertion shift whole elements.**